# Get all the details of sales order via order id in my controller?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, controllers, order-details

I want to get all the details of a sale order in my controller and then update the status of that order.

Plus how can I pass order ID in URL string and then get it as Magento 1.9 doesn't allow `$_GET[]` and `$_POST[]`

Comment: On admin or frontend?

Comment: i want to get the details on the frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you have entity id then use below code to get order details:**

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($entity_id);
```

If you have order increment id then use below code to get order details:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('10000001');
```

If you want to get data from post or get action then you can use the following code:

```
$order_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id'); //This will return only order id
```

And if you are posting multiple value from form or multiple parameters through url or get method then you need to use below code:

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

**Use below code for your form action:**

```
Mage::getUrl('frontname/controller/action', array('id' => 1));//If you want to pass only one parameter
```

> Output URL for above code: http://www.example.com/frontname/controller/action/id/1

And if you have multiple parameters then use below code:

```
Mage::getUrl('frontname/controller/action', array('id'=>1', '_query'=>array('parm1'=>'value1', 'parm2'=>'value2'))); //If you want to pass multiple parameters
```

> Output URL for above code:
>   http://www.example.com/frontname/controller/action/id/1/?parm1=value1&parm2=value2

Comment: $order_id = '100000003';
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('10000001');
print_r($order->getData());
 and this is returning me empty array, like this Array ( )

Comment: Put your order id instead of 10000001 like this $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id');

Comment: In loadByIncrementId function, we can't pass order  id, but it should be accepting increment id of the order, which might be different from order_id.

Comment: @Manish Joy, Did you saw the above comment where he mentioned that $order_id = '100000003'; which is not a order id. I think you are not checking what he is posting.

Comment: @SukumarGorai yes, I did, but he is using loadByIncrementId so he is putting correct value to the param, I guess

Comment: he is not using the variable order_id anywhere and yes, the variable name might be wrong as per usage

Comment: @Manish Joy: Check the first comment. Thats why I have mentioned it on second comment.

Comment: @SukumarGorai ok, my bad. I misunderstood bcz of wrong variable name

Comment: @ManishJoy Its okay. Happy Coding

Comment: @SukumarGorai in sales order table at the admin the column isn't it the order id ???

Comment: @Subhan No its a order increment ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can get order details by using this code snippet:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
```

BTW, you can get the parameter by using:

```
$this->getRequest()->getParam('index');
```

--or--

```
$this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Comment: this is returning me empty array, like this Array ( )

Comment: can you paste your code along with the question?